# Xamarin - Page Renderer (Apply on a specific page)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an issue regarding creating my own page renderer for a content page. What happens it that it applies to all of my pages even though I specifically implement it on a specific page.

So far, I've tried two methods:

**`CustomRenderer(Shared)`**

```
public class CustomPage : ContentPage {}
```

**`CustomRenderer (iOS)`**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace testApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.CustomPage
{
public class CustomPageRenderer: PageRenderer {}
}
```

**1st method: via XAML**

```
<customPage:CustomPage
x:Class="testApp.Views.testPage" 
xmlns:customPage="clr-namespace:OSMSeafarerApp.CustomControls.CustomPage">
</customPage:CustomPage>
```

**2nd method: via direct content page name (page name - testPage)** : I changed the assembly CustomPage to testPage so the result will be:|

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(testPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace testApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.CustomPage
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer: PageRenderer {}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or does creating page renderer affects all pages?

**EDIT1 SAMPLE:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(testPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace testApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.CustomPage
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer: PageRenderer 
    {
         NSObject _observerKeyboardShow;
         double _overlappedView;

         public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
         {
             base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

             var page = Element as testPage;

             if (page != null)
             {
                 var contentAsScrollView = page.Content as ScrollView;
                 if(contentAsScrollView != null)
                 {
                     return;
                 }

                 RegisterKeyboardShowNotifications();
             }

         }

         private void RegisterKeyboardShowNotifications()
         {
             if(_observerKeyboardShow == null)
             {
                 _observerKeyboardShow = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, whenKeyboardShow);
             }
         }

         private void whenKeyboardShow(NSNotification obj)
         {
             //ExampleOnly;

             var firstResponder = View.FindFirstResponder();
             var keyboardArea = UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(obj);
             _overlappedView = firstResponder.GetViewRelativeBottom(View);
             SlidePageUp(keyboardArea.Height, _overlappedView);
         }

         private void SlidePageUp(nfloat height, double overlappedView)
         {
             var pageSize = Element.Bounds;
             var _newY = pageSize.Y - CalculateNewSize(pageSize.Height, height, overlappedView);
         }


       }
}
```

Comment: `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]` is the correct usage. In your testpage.xaml.cs file, is it implementing ContentPage or CustomPage? Ie, `public class testpage : CustomPage {}`, and are you sure the other pages are not implementing CustomPage? Maybe add some code from another page that is appearing as a CustomPage instead of a ContentPage.

Comment: Exactly, this is the way I did it, the 1st method inheriting the `CustomPage` as the primary one, and I am sure that the other pages doesn't implement the `CustomPage`

Comment: @Swift_Talt Please share a simple sample to specify your issue.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Updated

Comment: @Swift_Talt I mean how do you use this page. Your renderer looks correct. From you code I guess the testPage is inheriting from the `CustomPage`. But the `xmlns:customPage="clr-namespace:OSMSeafarerApp.CustomControls.CustomPage"` looks a little weird.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Uhm, could you clarify it, why is it weird in some way? Is there another way to implement it solely in a page?